# How to verify results returned by EF Core query using debugger in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, linq-to-entities, visual-studio-debugging, entity-framework-core

In an ASP.NET MVC Core Web project, **without using any third party tools** (LINQPad etc.) how can we achieve the above for a LINQ query such as the one shown in an Action Method below.

**NOTE**:

1. I'm using `EF Core and VS2015`
2. Project is MVC `Code First`

**Action Method**:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostBlogs(string returnUrl = null)
{
    var qry = from a in _context.Blogs
             where a.Url.Contains("Contoso")

        return View(await qry.ToListAsync());
}
```

Comment: Expand the `qry` variable in a debugger?

Comment: do you need to see the generated SQL or what ?

Comment: @Sampath Generated SQL and the data `qry` is returning before it's sent to `View`

Comment: To inspect the resulting SQL: `qry.ToString()` in a Watch window

Answer (score 0):

To see the `query result` where you have to construct your method as shown below.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostBlogs(string returnUrl = null)
{
   var qry = from a in _context.Blogs
             where a.Url.Contains("Contoso");

       qry = await qry.ToListAsync();//you can see the result here when you expand it

       return View(qry);
}
```

You have to configure like this to see the SQL : [**Logging**](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/miscellaneous/logging.html)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Your solution is close to what I'm looking for but EF Core does not have _context.Database.Log. It was valid in EF 6. I'm using EF Core as mentioned in a tag of my post.

Comment: @nam， what about this issue? Could you get helpful information from Sampath's suggestion?